# GCP Custom Prediction Routine unable to include jsonschema depency specified in setup.py

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-ai-platform

According to GCP AI Platform's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines#predictor-tarball), Custom Prediction Routine deployment should allow to include PyPI dependencies. I included my dependency of jsonschema like below in my `setup.py` script:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages


REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['jsonschema']

setup(
    name='custom_code',
    version='1.0.2',
    scripts=['predictor.py', 'preprocess.py'],
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True
)
```

but got this error message when deploying:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Unexpected error when loading the model: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' (Error code: 0)"
```

The same error persisted when specifying a version like so `REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['jsonschema==3.2.0']`. I then used a lower version:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages


REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['jsonschema==3.0.0']

setup(
    name='custom_code',
    version='1.0.2',
    scripts=['predictor.py', 'preprocess.py'],
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True
)
```

but now got this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Unexpected error when loading the model: problem in predictor - DistributionNotFound: The 'jsonschema' distribution was not found and is required by the application (Error code: 0)"
```

What can go wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the initial error `Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Unexpected error when loading the model: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' (Error code: 0)"` was actually driven by a model format issue. This seems to be [a known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44467) with TensorFlow Keras (although my TF version is 1.15, the quoted TF version was 2.1.0). Once I used the [TensorFlow SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/experimental/export_saved_model), the error immediately went away, and I was also able to include jsonchema dependency with the `setup.py` file as is.